# How to disable Chunked transfer in IIS?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have two websites that basically use the same code base, lets called them A & B.  When I upload A and run, the site is not chunked.  When I debug and test B, the page is not Chunked but when it is run from the server, the pages become chunked.  Is there a setting in IIS or web.config that disables Chunking of the page.  Any ideas on how to identify why the page is chunking?

Comment: Settings for Chunked transfer in IIS. Left double click site->ASP->Enable Chunked Encoding.

Comment: Yes, saw that but Enabled Chunked is true and disabled.  Its the same as the other site but is not chunked.

Comment: How about config about chunked transfer encoding in your project? I have an idea, you could set Response.BufferOutput =true. It means that it must sent to the browser only when the page completes its processing.

Comment: Good Idea, I stuck your idea + Buffer = true in the Global.asax.cs file in beginrequest, the Content-Length still does not appear and its only one site that seems to be affected.

Comment: It now seems if the file is a certain size, it will be chunked, otherwise Content-Length will be show.  I want to increase the size of a page before IIS chunks the output.

Answer (score 0):

It does not appear to be editable at the site level. At the server-level node in IIS, you can go to (IIS Section) ASP > Enable Chunked Encoding.